# PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: lettuce redis cluster error

Tags: java, redis, truststore, lettuce

I've a below java program to connect to a secured redis cluster.

```java
package org.example;

import io.lettuce.core.RedisURI;
import io.lettuce.core.SocketOptions;
import io.lettuce.core.TimeoutOptions;
import io.lettuce.core.cluster.ClusterClientOptions;
import io.lettuce.core.cluster.ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions;
import io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient;
import io.lettuce.core.cluster.api.async.RedisAdvancedClusterAsyncCommands;
import io.lettuce.core.codec.ByteArrayCodec;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        RedisURI uri = RedisURI.create("rediss://redis.internal.cloud.com:6379");
        uri.setVerifyPeer(true);
        RedisClusterClient rcc = RedisClusterClient.create(uri);
        ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions tc = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder().refreshPeriod(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)).enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers().build();
        ClusterClientOptions.Builder options = ClusterClientOptions.builder().topologyRefreshOptions(tc);
        SocketOptions so = SocketOptions.builder()
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .tcpNoDelay(true)
                .keepAlive(false)
                .build();
        TimeoutOptions to = TimeoutOptions.builder()
                .timeoutCommands(true)
                .fixedTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .build();
        ClusterClientOptions cco = options.socketOptions(so).timeoutOptions(to)
                .cancelCommandsOnReconnectFailure(true)
                .pingBeforeActivateConnection(true)
                .build();
                rcc.setOptions(cco);
        RedisAdvancedClusterAsyncCommands conn = rcc.connect(new ByteArrayCodec()).async();
    }
}
```

The redis labs has provided `redis_ca.pem` I don't know how to use that connect.

When I run the code I get below exception -

> Jun 16, 2023 10:46:12 PM io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh lambda$openConnections$12
> WARNING: Unable to connect to [redis-11748.internal.c19953.us-west-2-mz.ec2.cloud.rlrcp.com:11748]: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Exception in thread "main" io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to establish a connection to Redis Cluster
> at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.lambda$assertInitialPartitions$26(RedisClusterClient.java:926)
> at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.get(RedisClusterClient.java:945)
> at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.assertInitialPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:925)
> at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connect(RedisClusterClient.java:401)
> at org.example.RedisClient.main(RedisClient.java:36)
> Caused by: io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh$CannotRetrieveClusterPartitions: Cannot retrieve cluster partitions from [rediss://redis.internal.cloud.com:6379]
>
> Details:
> [rediss://redis.internal.cloud.com:6379]: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>
> Suppressed: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to [redis-11748.internal.c19953.us-west-2-mz.ec2.cloud.rlrcp.com:11748]: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$openConnections$12(DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh.java:347)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
> at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$null$5(AbstractRedisClient.java:470)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
> at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisHandshakeHandler.lambda$fail$4(RedisHandshakeHandler.java:139)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:185)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
> at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisHandshakeHandler.fail(RedisHandshakeHandler.java:138)
> at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisHandshakeHandler.lambda$channelActive$3(RedisHandshakeHandler.java:107)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
> at io.lettuce.core.RedisHandshake.lambda$tryHandshakeResp3$1(RedisHandshake.java:115)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
> at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.doCompleteExceptionally(AsyncCommand.java:139)
> at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeExceptionally(AsyncCommand.java:132)
> at io.lettuce.core.RedisHandshake.lambda$dispatch$7(RedisHandshake.java:263)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118)
> at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
> at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:57)
> at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:31)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118)
> at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
> at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:57)
> at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:31)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118)
> at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
> at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:57)
> at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:31)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractCoalescingBufferQueue.releaseAndCompleteAll(AbstractCoalescingBufferQueue.java:350)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractCoalescingBufferQueue.releaseAndFailAll(AbstractCoalescingBufferQueue.java:208)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:864)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:800)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleUnwrapThrowable(SslHandler.java:1276)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1250)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1294)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1558)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1404)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1245)
> ... 20 more
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
> ... 31 more
> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
> at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
> at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
> ... 37 more

I also tried to import pem using the below command -

```
$ keytool -import -alias RedislabsCA -keystore ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/lib/security/cacerts -file ~/redis_ca.pem -storepass changeit -noprompt
Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore
Certificate was added to keystore

Warning:
The input uses the SHA1withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.
```

How can I configure truststore and password correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the cert provided into the default truststore (CACERTS) correctly.

It looks like the host being called (redis.internal.cloud.com) does not have a cert signed by redis_ca.pem or the hostname on the cert is wrong. Try to [pull the cert with openssl](https://serverfault.com/questions/661978/displaying-a-remote-ssl-certificate-details-using-cli-tools) and check against cert in redis_ca.pem.

Try adding the actual host cert to CACERTS truststore.